# How to install Punjabi Language font in android samsung galaxy?

Tags: android-emulator

i have an Android Phone, Samsung Galaxy Pop and I want my phone to read the Punjabi font too. So can you tell me how to install Punjabi font in my mobile Phone.
suggest me any solution for it.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check out this app:

http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/gurmukhi-keyboard_rppe.html

The app provides an input method in Gurmukhi Locale with dictionary support. Hopefully it is what you're looking for! (btw I have the same phone, good choice)

Comment: Actually i am making an android application but i want to show Punjabi text in it.But while i write Punjabi text in my Text view it shows me boxes in the emulator than i save an .ttf file in the asset folder in my application But still it does show me proper punjabi language it shows boxes somewhere. give any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I was able to install punjabi fonts on G1 a couple of years ago. Should work now as well. However as it involves replacing a fallback font your phone has to be rooted to do that. http://arvinderkang.com/2009/12/03/gurmukhi-on-mobile/